# La firma del canva se borra cuando se separa el dedo de la pantalla en el móvil

Tags: javascript, jquery, signature

estoy usando un plugin de jquery para capturar una firma, el plugin es el siguiente: https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/183525/Save-digital-signature-in-Database-and-display-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-C-and-VBNet/

En las computadoras funciona bien pero cuando paso a un móvil sucede que al momento de que la persona esta poniendo la firma y separa su dedo de la pantalla y vuelve a hacer algún trazo se pierde lo que anteriormente se tenia, como comento eso solo pasa en el celular, ¿saben cómo podría solucionarlo?, de antemano gracias, DTB.

```js
            $(function () {
                $('#colors_sketch').sketch();
                $('#borrar').bind("click", function () {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('colors_sketch');
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    $('#colors_sketch').sketch('actions', []);
                   
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mobomo/sketch.js/master/lib/sketch.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tools">
                                <a href="#colors_sketch" id="borrar" data-clear='true' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Borrar <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <canvas id="colors_sketch" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%; height: 200px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

no conozco la librería pero te puedo recomendar drawingboard.js ya que llevo bastantes años utilizándola y bastante fácil de usar, además de muy personalizable, te comparto un codepen con un ejemplo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var customBoard2 = new DrawingBoard.Board("custom-board-2", {
    controls: [
      "Color",
      {
        Size: {
          type: "dropdown"
        }
      },
      {
        DrawingMode: {
          filler: false
        }
      },
      "Navigation",
      "Download"
    ],
    size: 1,
    webStorage: "local",
    enlargeYourContainer: true
  });

  $("#logImgBtn").click(function(e) {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("drawing-board-custom-board-2"));
  });
});
```

```css
​
/* drawingboard.js v0.4.6 - https://github.com/Leimi/drawingboard.js
* Copyright (c) 2015 Emmanuel Pelletier
* Licensed MIT */

.drawing-board,
.drawing-board * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box
}

.drawing-board-controls-hidden,
.drawing-board-utils-hidden {
  display: none!important
}

.drawing-board {
  position: relative;
  display: block
}

.drawing-board-canvas-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd
}

.drawing-board-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  cursor: crosshair;
  z-index: 20
}

.drawing-board-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 30
}

.drawing-board-control-colors-rainbows,
.drawing-board-control-size .drawing-board-control-inner,
.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown,
.drawing-board-control>button {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -2px #121212, inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -2px #121212, inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  height: 28px
}

.drawing-board-control>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 28px;
  line-height: 14px
}

.drawing-board-control>button:focus,
.drawing-board-control>button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.drawing-board-control>button.active,
.drawing-board-control>button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  background-color: #ddd
}

.drawing-board-control>button[disabled] {
  color: gray
}

.drawing-board-control>button[disabled].active,
.drawing-board-control>button[disabled]:active,
.drawing-board-control>button[disabled]:focus,
.drawing-board-control>button[disabled]:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -2px #121212, inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px -2px #121212, inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  cursor: default
}

.drawing-board-controls {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 9.33px 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 28px
}

.drawing-board-controls[data-align=left] {
  margin: 0;
  left: -9.33px
}

.drawing-board-controls[data-align=right] {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  right: -9.33px
}

.drawing-board-canvas-wrapper+.drawing-board-controls,
.drawing-board-controls+.drawing-board-canvas-wrapper {
  margin-top: 5px
}

.drawing-board-controls-hidden {
  height: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0
}

.drawing-board-control {
  display: table-cell;
  border-collapse: separate;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%
}

.drawing-board-control-inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.drawing-board-control>button {
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.drawing-board-control-colors {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0
}

.drawing-board-control-colors-current {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px
}

.drawing-board-control-colors-rainbows {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 33px;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px
}

.drawing-board-control-colors-rainbow {
  height: 18px
}

.drawing-board-control-colors-picker:first-child {
  margin-right: 5px
}

.drawing-board-control-colors-picker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.drawing-board-control-colors-picker[data-color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"] {
  width: 16px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none
}

.drawing-board-control-colors-picker:hover {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #555
}

.drawing-board-control-drawingmode>button {
  margin-right: 2px
}

.drawing-board-control-drawingmode>button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}

.drawing-board-control-drawingmode-pencil-button {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.drawing-board-control-drawingmode-pencil-button:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%
}

.drawing-board-control-drawingmode-eraser-button {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.drawing-board-control-drawingmode-eraser-button:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%
}

.drawing-board-control-drawingmode-filler-button {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.drawing-board-control-drawingmode-filler-button:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%
}

.drawing-board-control-navigation>button {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 2px
}

.drawing-board-control-navigation>button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}

.drawing-board-control-size[data-drawing-board-type=range] .drawing-board-control-inner {
  width: 75px
}

.drawing-board-control-size[data-drawing-board-type=dropdown] .drawing-board-control-inner {
  overflow: visible
}

.drawing-board-control-size-range-input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0
}

.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown span,
.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown-current span,
.drawing-board-control-size-range-current {
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  opacity: .8
}

.drawing-board-control-size-range-current {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: .15;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 50
}

.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown-current {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown-current span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%
}

.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px;
  top: 33px;
  height: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100
}

.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown li {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  min-height: 16px
}

.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown li:hover {
  background: #ccc
}

.drawing-board-control-size-dropdown span {
  margin: 0 auto
}

.drawing-board-control-download-button {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.drawing-board-control-download-button:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/drawingboard.js/0.4.6/drawingboard.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-board-2" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"></div>
<button id="logImgBtn">Log image</button>
```

https://codepen.io/romeroedward18/pen/YzjNwNr?editors=1111

https://leimi.github.io/drawingboard.js/?utm_source=cdnjs&utm_medium=cdnjs_link&utm_campaign=cdnjs_library

Comment: El código de tu respuesta debe ir en la respuesta como texto y no en un enlace externo. El motivo? El enlace puede dejar de funcionar, dejando tu respuesta totalmente inservible. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras listo ya lo edito